# Finite conjugacy classes in hyperbolic groups.

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a word hyperbolic group, and $a\in G$ an element of finite order.

> Can the conjugacy class $a^G$ be infinite ?

Comment: Yes of course. The simplest example is probably an element of order $2$ in an infinite dihedral group.

Comment: Actually, no matter what (nonelementary) hyperbolic group you take, unless $a$ is contained in a finite normal subgroup of $G$, the conjugacy class of $a$ will be infinite.